# How to get a std::vector that supports negative indices?

Tags: c++, vector, indexing, stl, std

I have a vector. What I want to do is store a value at the first index of the vector. However, this value is for errors and so I would like to refer to this value like `vector_ [-1]`. How do I go about with this?

I came up with one solution.
What I'm doing is creating a new vector and assigning the new vector to this vector.

```
vector_.resize(required_size+1);
vector_ = std::vector<T> (vector_.begin()+1,vector_.end());
```

At this point could I legally use `vector_[-1]`? If not, please help me with other solutions.

**EDIT**
I found a workaround. Though its not vectors with negative indexing, I'm using a pointer to the second member of the vector so when I do `ptr[-1]`, it points to the first element of the vector.

Comment: No, this is wrong. Maybe store it elsewhere?

Comment: There's no way to index an unchanged `std::vector` with a negative index. You need to make your own class, perhaps using `std::vector` internally.

Comment: The index for the vector is essentially a memory offset. So -1 would be invalid. Seems to me your indexes have special meaning and are more like keys instead. Maybe an std::map would be more appropriate for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @KubaOber That's actually an answer.

Comment: @tdemay, yes -1 would be invalid. But I want `vector_` to point to the second element so that when I say `vector_[-1]` it points to the first element. There is no illegal memory access here

Comment: @Rakshith: you can do that with an array, but not with a vector.

Comment: @Rakshith : Can you please elaborate what do you mean by vector_ to point to the second element.

Comment: Why use `-1` for this? It sounds like you want index `0` to have a _special_ meaning so if you're not going to create a new type then use `std::vector` with a convention that uses the `0` index for the error and avoid the confusing `-1` syntax.

Comment: When I say `vector_[0]`, it should actually refer to the second element of the initially allocated vector memory. `vector_[-1]` should give me the actual first element. Just want the indexes to start from -1. Because negative index means an error in my code

Comment: `vector_[-1]` actually means `vector[std::numeric_limits<std::vector::size_type>::max()]`, because `std::vector::size_type` is unsigned. You will never be able to have a negative index in `std::vector`

Comment: You cannot change what vector does internally. It is what _internally_ means. Your best bet is to create your own class which will _internally_ convert indices to those expected by vector.

Comment: Index `0` of a `std::vector` should never refer to the second argument because no one would expect it to work that way. Do what @KubaOber suggested and create a new type which may have any semantics you desire.

Comment: @Rakshith, but it is invalid memory access. It's direct access to memory. That's why it's so fast. It works just like a C-Style array would. You are asking it to go to the beginning of the block of memory for the vector and go backwards sizeof(value_type)

Comment: actually @KABoissonneault is right. I forgot about it being unsigned. You will not be going backwards, you'd be jumping forward MAXINT.

Comment: What is your expectation of the behavior of begin ()? size ()? If you add one of these vectors to another?

Comment: What do you mean @kfsone

Comment: @Rakshith If you have a vector that has a [-1] index, what would you expect `begin()` to return? The -1 element or the 0th element? Would you expect `size()` to include the -1 element or to return `actual_size() - 1`? This affects code like `if (index < v.size()) return v[index]`. For a newly constructed `negative_index_vector`, if I do a `push_back` does it go into position -1 or position 0? Is the vector empty if only the -1 index is populated? If not, then `if (!v.empty()) return v[0]` is broken, but if it is then how do you tell if the -1th element is present/populated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the basic starting point of a vector where you can specify the (signed) lower and upper indexes

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


template<class T>
struct any_index_vector
{
    any_index_vector(int min, int max)
    : _zero_index(min)
    , _storage((max - min))
    {
        // assert min - max
    }

    T& operator[](int index)
    {
        assert(index >= lower_limit());
        assert(index <= upper_limit());
        return _storage[index - _zero_index];
    }

    T& operator[](int index) const
    {
        assert(index >= lower_limit());
        assert(index <= upper_limit());
        return _storage[index - _zero_index];
    }

    int upper_limit() const {
        return _zero_index + int(_storage.size());
    }

    int lower_limit() const {
        return _zero_index;
    }

    int extent() const {
        return upper_limit() - lower_limit();
    }

    int _zero_index = 0;
    std::vector<T> _storage {};
};

int main()
{
    any_index_vector<int> v(-1, 9);
    for (int i = -1 ; i < 10 ; ++i) {
        v[i] = (i+6);
    }

    for (int i = -1 ; i < 10 ; ++i) {
        std::cout << "position: " << std::setw(2) << i << " : " << v[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

expected output:

```
position: -1 : 5
position:  0 : 6
position:  1 : 7
position:  2 : 8
position:  3 : 9
position:  4 : 10
position:  5 : 11
position:  6 : 12
position:  7 : 13
position:  8 : 14
position:  9 : 15
```

Comment: Can you make this answer simple and beginner friendly? I do not follow the code

Comment: @Rakshith you can copy paste the entire program into your IDE and single-step through it.

Comment: @Rakshith It's about as simple as it gets. You can look up the dictionary definitions of the terms limit and extent, they are used in their usual meaning.

Answer (score 2):

**You can not have negative indices** in [c++-standard-library](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-standard-library), unless of course *you* provide your own class of a vector that decays that.

For, example check the [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/):

> Prototype: `reference operator[] (size_type n);`
>
> Parameters: n Position
>   of an element in the container. Notice that the first element has a
>   position of 0 (not 1). Member type size_type is an unsigned integral
>   type.

Here is a class that could do what you want:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class myVector {
public:
  int get(int index) { return v[index + 1]; }
  void push_back(int value) { v.push_back(value); }
  void print() {
      for(unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << v[i] << " ";
      std::cout << "\n";
  }
  const int& operator[](int index) const { return v[index + 1]; }
private:
  std::vector<int> v;
};

int main() {
  myVector v;
  v.push_back(404); // error code
  v.push_back(32);  // real data
  v.print();
  std::cout << v[-1] << std::endl;
  std::cout << v.get(-1) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output ([Live Demo](http://cpp.sh/2bmt)):

```
404 32 
404
404
```

Since you are new to C++, operator overloading might puzzle you, skip it for now and come back later and read [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading).

Comment: Thanks @gsamaras. Didn't expect such quick replies!

Comment: @Rakshith Except it doesn't work: it's not a bidirectional random access container that `std::vector` is. Designing container classes isn't exactly a beginner's job, and answers such as this trivialize the matter to the point of uselessness. All the other answers at the moment suffer from this issue :(

Comment: Will it be useful to inherit `myVector` from `std::vector`? Then all the functionality of `std::vector` could be reused and only the needed parts changed.

Comment: @ilya1725 Only as long as you **privately** inherit from `std::vector`, and explicitly expose the functionality you need through `using` in a public section. `myVector` is not a `std::vector` anymore once its indexing is reimplemented. Don't break [LSP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/56860/1329652)!

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand why you want to do this. You could as well store the extra value in the first element and access it via `vector_[0]`. However, if you insist on using -1 as index, then I see only one proper way to do this:

```
template<typename T>
class {
public:  
    T& operator[](int index){
        if (index==-1) { return value; }
        else { return vector[index]; }
    }
private:
    T value;
    std::vector<T> vector;
}
```

However, I would strongly suggest not to start something like this. You will waste lots of code just to get something that acts similar to a vector while you could simply use a plain `std::vector` and forget about the -1 indexing.

Comment: Definitely. Think about all the other things you'd have to wrap just to get that non-feature...